# Javascript Issue, my div won't move

Tags: javascript

yesterday in class my teacher put up some code for us to test at home but I can't seem to get the code to work. What the code is suppose to do is move a div while holding the mouse down. I showed my friend and we think the problem is here:

```
calculator.style.top = getStyle(calculator, "top");
calculator.style.left = getStyle(calculator, "left");

function getStyle(object,styleName)
{
 if (window.getComputedStyle)
  {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
  }
 else if (object.currentStyle)
   {
    return object.currentStyle[styleName];
   }
}
```

but we still can't seem to make it work. Help would be extremely appreciated. Also here is the full code just in case you need to see it:

```
diffx = null;
diffy = null;
off = document.getElementById("buttonOff");
on = document.getElementById("calcButton");
calculator = document.getElementById("calculator");
calculator.style.top = getStyle(calculator, "top");
calculator.style.left = getStyle(calculator, "left");

function getStyle(object,styleName)
{
 if (window.getComputedStyle)
  {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(object, null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
  }
 else if (object.currentStyle)
   {
    return object.currentStyle[styleName];
   }
}

function grabCalculator(e)
{
            var evt = e || window.event;
            calculator = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
            var mousex = evt.clientX;
            var mousey = evt.clientY;
            diffx = parseInt(calculator.style.left) – mousex;
            diffy = parseInt(calculator.style.top) – mousey;
            addEvent(document, "mousemove", moveCalculator, false);
            addEvent(document, "mouseup", dropCalculator, false);
}

function moveCalculator(e)
{
            var evt = e || window.event;
            var mousex = evt.clientX;
            var mousey = evt.clientY;
            calculator.style.left = mousex + diffx + "px";
            calculator.style.top = mousey + diffy + "px";
}

function addEvent(obj, eventType, fnName, cap)
{
            if (obj.attachEvent)
            {
                        obj.attachEvent("on" + eventType, fnName);
            }

            else
            {
                        obj.addEventListener(eventType, fnName, cap);
            }
}

function removeEvent(obj, eventType, fnName, cap)
{
            if (obj.attachEvent)
            {
                        obj.detachEvent("off" + eventType, fnName);
            }

            else
            {
                obj.removeEventListener(eventType, fnName, cap);
            }
}

function dropCalculator(e)
{
            removeEvent(document,"mousemove", moveCalculator, false);
            removeEvent(document, "mouseup", dropCalculator, false);
}

function main() {
    alert("TEST");
    //store top and left values of calculator
    calculator.style.top = getStyle(calculator, "top");
    calculator.style.left = getStyle(calculator, "left");
    calcButtonState = true;

}

window.onload = main;
```

Thanks again!
Sandro

---

Edit: 
added Jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/7225J/

(Also the output looks horrible because its not suppose to be resized to that small)

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? And could you possibly make a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the grabCalculator function.
Try changing:

```
diffx = parseInt(calculator.style.left) – mousex;
diffy = parseInt(calculator.style.top) – mousey;
```

To:

```
diffx = parseInt(calculator.offsetLeft) – mousex;
diffy = parseInt(calculator.offsetTop) – mousey;
```

also put this in main:

```
addEvent(..., grabCalculator, ...);
```

Comment: Did you run this in a js debugger? (preferably firefox with firebug) Any output?

Comment: I did not. I don't have a js debugger actually haha. I guess its time to get one huh

Answer (score 0):

in main, set the initial calculator coords like so:

```
calculator.style.top = 0 + "px";
calculator.style.left = 0 + "px";
```

Don't use getStyle at all. Just directly access it after. It will work because you put those 2 lines into the main.